# How to pass attributes to 3rd party FormView in Django?

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to use django-password-reset, and this is my first attempt with class-based forms, especially 3rd party. In the [documentation](https://django-password-reset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#attributes) I see a bunch of attributes I can use. But how exactly (where in my code) do I set for example `case_sensitive`? All I have so far is a bunch of templates and this line in urls.py: `url(r'^password/', include('password_reset.urls')),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think overriding the third-party view might be helpful.

```
from password_reset.views import Reset


class ResetOverridView(Reset):
    # override your attributes here
    template_name = "my_template.html"
```

and mention this view *explicitly* as,

```
urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'my/path/', ResetOverridView.as_view())

              ]
```

Note: I didn't try this solution and I have no previous experience with this lib

**UPDATE-1**
Won't this approach create a URL resolution conflict?
Obviously, unless you define different *`regex-pattern`* for both.
From the [doc](https://django-password-reset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#usage),

> `include('password_reset.urls')` in your root `urls.py`

`include()` function doesn't create any url-patterns. It should be as

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'my/path/', include('password_reset.urls'))
]
```

Which means, you have to mention some *regex* along with **`include()`**.

So what I'm suggesting is, create a url-patterns as,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'password/app/', include('password_reset.urls')),
    url(r'password/my/path/reset/', ResetOverridView.as_view())
]
```

I'm not sure whether it's a **pythonic way** or not, but we don't have much information about this thing from *official-doc*

Comment: Won't this approach create a URL resolution conflict? If the original path was `/password/recover/` (defined by `include('password_reset.urls')`), and I'd now point it to my view, is it a pythonic way to go?

Comment: In url's in your answer, should it maybe be `ResetOverridView` rather than `Reset`?

Comment: @texnic yeah...my mistake.